# ./configure gets stuck on checking the max length of command line arguments

Tags: libraries, configure, csh, weather

I am installing and building several libraries for the personal user version of the WRF weather model. The user guide I am using is found here: https://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php#STEP2.

I am on Windows 10, running the terminal emulator MSYS. I have been following the instructions for each of the five libraries so far without any unresolvable issue overall. When I got to the Jasper library instructions, I got up to the point of

`./configure --prefix=$DIR/grib2 --build=x86_64`.

When I ran this, the checking messages continued until the

`checking the maximum length of command line arguments...`

check. It stops there and doesn't continue, despite waiting for it and restarting `./configure` several times. I am unaware of what I should try next that wouldn't risk causing problems. None of the other `./configure`s gave me any issues, except for the build type, which was resolved with `--build=x86_64`.

If anyone needs more information for a fix, please ask away!

Comment: This seems to be a windows cli problem.

Comment: Maybe config.log has some useful information?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @Alex Hamilton ?